# React app: props do not get updated externally

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, react-props

I have a React app that gets initialized as simple as:

```
let globalTodos = some_fetch_from_localstorage();

...

function changeGlobalTodos() {
  globalTodos = another_fetch_from_localstorage();
}

...

ReactDOM.render(<ReactApp todos={globalTodos} />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Inside of the app I'm doing the following:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    todos: []
  };
}

static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
  if (nextProps.todos !== prevState.todos) {
    return { todos: nextProps.todos };
  } else return null;
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if (prevProps.todos !== this.props.todos) {
    this.setState({ todos: this.props.todos });
  }
}
```

The problem is that whenever I update `globalTodos`, the props on the React app don't get updated: it stays on the initial `globalTodos`'s value.

I have tried playing with `getDerivedStateFromProps` is being called only on first setup of the props while `componentDidUpdate` never gets called :-/

What am I missing here?

Comment: React only re execute render component when change `state`, You can use state store `globalTodos`.

Comment: @GQSM would you mind giving an example of how to mutate state on props change for this case? Have tried `getDerivedStateFromProps` and it doesn't get triggered on `globalTodos` change somehow. Neither does `componentDidUpdate`. Would appreciate any direction.

Comment: Hey, @spliter, React does not watch for mutations on props and state. You must tell react to change it's state by calling 'setState', when this is called a re-render is triggered, the state is mutated (by react) and the changes can be seen. I recommend going through their tutorial, they cover all the basics https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#lifting-state-up

Answer (score 0):

I can't leave a comment, so I'll just post this here.  React won't re-render unless you're updating a state.

I'd make globalTodos a state and add onto it from there using setState, then you can pass that on as a prop to the child component in your case ReactApp. You don't need to change them as states in your child component.

Example:

```
class Parent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            globalTodos: initialFetchedArray
        };
    }

    changeGlobalTodos() {
        let newTodos = fetchNewArray;
        this.setState({globalTodos: newTodos});
    }

    ReactDOM.render(<ReactApp todos={globalTodos} />, document.getElementById('app'));
}

//You just need your prop here, here you can do whatever you want to do with the array if it's display you can use map
class Child extends Component {
    render {
        return(
         {this.props.todos}
        )
    }
}
```

Really the main thing here is making your globalTodos a state, using setState to change that state, and just passing that state down as a prop.

Comment: Thanks Mike, but my scenario is not as you describe it unfortunately: I don't have React above the `ReactApp` (that's why it has `App` in the name), it's not a "child component". So it's the top most React node. Above it is only regular DOM and I change `globalTodos` from vanilla JS that knows nothing about React's state.